# Why are shared libraries (.so files) loaded as private?

Tags: linux, shared-libraries, .so

This is from an smaps file:
`b750d000-b76bc000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 918842     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so`
The `p` in `r-xp` indicates it is loaded as private, I believe. Why is this so? Doesn't this defeat the purpose of shared libraries if a copy of each .so file is loaded into different memory addresses for different processes? What advantage does this private loading offer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`p` corresponds to `MAP_PRIVATE`. `man mmap` claims that:

> **`MAP_PRIVATE`**: Create a private **copy-on-write** mapping.  Updates to the mapping are not visible to other processes mapping the same file, and are not carried through to the  underlying file.  [...]

The physical memory pages for this VMA will be shared by all processes **as long as no modification** is done (they are shared with the kernel cache as well). When a virtual page is modified in a given process, the page is duplicated (unshared) for this process (**copy-on-write**).

Let's look at:

```
$ cat /proc/self/maps
00400000-0040c000 r-xp 00000000 08:11 529223                             /bin/cat
0060b000-0060c000 r--p 0000b000 08:11 529223                             /bin/cat
0060c000-0060d000 rw-p 0000c000 08:11 529223                             /bin/cat
[...]
```

- The first and second VMAs are read-only. They will (typically) not be modified and will (typically) be shared by all processes.
- The third VMA (`rw-p`) is writeable but the modifications in one process must be nor visible in other processes. This VMA contains the (mutable) global variables which are not shared by different processes.